# FancyBox open another (background scrolling)

Tags: jquery, fancybox

If I open a Fancybox on a click:

```
<a class="iconlink2" id="variouscontact" href="#inlineterms">TEXT</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#variouscontact").fancybox({
            'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        });
    });
    </script>
```

But now if I want to open another Fancybox from the Fancybox (link) in the second Fancybox the background is scrollable. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Hi @Andy these previous posts should help.


  - [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631124/how-to-prevent-scrolling-of-page-behind-fancybox-2
 - [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453743/fancybox-v2-how-do-i-prevent-background-scrolling-in-chrome

Comment: Hi, i have tested few ways now but i dont get it working, do you have an example with my code above?