# Fancybox gallery scrolls to top

Tags: jquery, scroll, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have added a gallery using fancybox to a webpage I'm working on. The problem I'm having is that the gallery thumbs have been placed towards the middle of the page and when I click on any of the thumbs the larger image scrolls to the top of the page. How can I stop this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547007/fancybox2-fancy-box-causes-page-to-to-jump-to-the-top. Jordanj77 is correct but easiest solution is to just go to stylesheet jquery.fancybox.css and comment out the row saying overflow: hidden !important; in section .fancybox-lock

Comment: If you are using fancybox v2.1.5 it seems that the issue has been fixed in the latest master that you can download form here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip so no more hacks to either the js or css files.

Comment: You actually don't need to comment it out. You just need to change it to `overflow: visible !important;` and you'll be good.