# jquery fancybox parent gets scrolled to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox, scrolltop

I have a problem when I open a fancybox/lightbox, the parent window gets scrolled to top :(

How can I keep parent window scroll location when opening a fancybox/lightbox?

My parent page is a long list of links and users are complaining about when they close the fancybox they have to scroll back and find the link they clicked on (and click on the next link if searched info not found).

I use fancybox v.2.1.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547007/fancybox2-fancybox-causes-page-to-to-jump-to-the-top

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get the latest version that you can download from here:
https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip

That bug has been fixed in that release.
Please note the version from the main website http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ is outdated so that's why you have to download and install the latest master.